# Ошибка запуска демона Namenode c логом ошибок

Tags: демон, unix, map-reduce, java, linux

Я пытался запустить `namenode` c помощью скрипта

```
./start-all.sh
```

и в лог-файле обнаружил следующие сообщения (привожу сообщения только для `handler`)

```
2013-02-18 02:36:18,267 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = one/192.168.1.8
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.0.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r 1243785; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Tue Feb 14 08:15:38 UTC 2012
************************************************************/
2013-02-18 02:36:18,489 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-02-18 02:36:18,505 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-02-18 02:36:18,506 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-02-18 02:36:18,506 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2013-02-18 02:36:18,715 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-02-18 02:36:18,723 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-02-18 02:36:18,729 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2013-02-18 02:36:18,731 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source NameNode registered.
2013-02-18 02:36:18,753 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 32-bit
2013-02-18 02:36:18,756 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2% max memory = 19.33375 MB
2013-02-18 02:36:18,756 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^22 = 4194304 entries
2013-02-18 02:36:18,756 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=4194304, actual=4194304
2013-02-18 02:36:18,848 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=hadoop
2013-02-18 02:36:18,848 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
2013-02-18 02:36:18,848 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true
2013-02-18 02:36:18,853 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
2013-02-18 02:36:18,854 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
2013-02-18 02:36:18,957 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean
2013-02-18 02:36:18,990 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
2013-02-18 02:36:19,003 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Number of files = 1
2013-02-18 02:36:19,007 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Number of files under construction = 0
2013-02-18 02:36:19,007 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Image file of size 112 loaded in 0 seconds.
2013-02-18 02:36:19,013 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Edits file /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/dfs/name/current/edits of size 4 edits # 0 loaded in 0 seconds.
2013-02-18 02:36:19,014 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Image file of size 112 saved in 0 seconds.
2013-02-18 02:36:19,023 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Image file of size 112 saved in 0 seconds.
2013-02-18 02:36:19,031 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameCache: initialized with 0 entries 0 lookups
2013-02-18 02:36:19,031 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Finished loading FSImage in 194 msecs
2013-02-18 02:36:19,053 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Total number of blocks = 0
2013-02-18 02:36:19,053 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of invalid blocks = 0
2013-02-18 02:36:19,054 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of under-replicated blocks = 0
2013-02-18 02:36:19,054 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of  over-replicated blocks = 0
2013-02-18 02:36:19,054 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Safe mode termination scan for invalid, over- and under-replicated blocks completed in 16 msec
2013-02-18 02:36:19,054 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Leaving safe mode after 0 secs.
2013-02-18 02:36:19,054 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Network topology has 0 racks and 0 datanodes
2013-02-18 02:36:19,054 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* UnderReplicatedBlocks has 0 blocks
2013-02-18 02:36:19,062 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.HostsFileReader: Refreshing hosts (include/exclude) list
2013-02-18 02:36:19,068 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source FSNamesystemMetrics registered.
2013-02-18 02:36:19,085 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcDetailedActivityForPort7000 registered.
2013-02-18 02:36:19,086 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcActivityForPort7000 registered.
2013-02-18 02:36:19,088 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Namenode up at: one/192.168.1.8:7000
2013-02-18 02:36:19,094 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: ReplicateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: First cycle completed 0 blocks in 2 msec
2013-02-18 02:36:19,094 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: ReplicateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: Queue flush completed 0 blocks in 2 msec processing time, 2 msec clock time, 1 cycles
2013-02-18 02:36:19,094 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: InvalidateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: First cycle completed 0 blocks in 0 msec
2013-02-18 02:36:19,094 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: InvalidateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: Queue flush completed 0 blocks in 0 msec processing time, 0 msec clock time, 1 cycles
2013-02-18 02:36:19,095 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting SocketReader
2013-02-18 02:36:49,141 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2013-02-18 02:36:49,231 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added global filtersafety (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
2013-02-18 02:36:49,246 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: dfs.webhdfs.enabled = false
2013-02-18 02:36:49,256 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 50070
2013-02-18 02:36:49,257 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: listener.getLocalPort() returned 50070 webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() returned 50070
2013-02-18 02:36:49,257 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 50070
2013-02-18 02:36:49,257 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2013-02-18 02:36:49,553 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50070
2013-02-18 02:36:49,553 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Web-server up at: 0.0.0.0:50070
2013-02-18 02:36:49,623 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 9 on 7000: starting
2013-02-18 02:36:49,624 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 8 on 7000: starting
2013-02-18 02:36:49,624 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 7 on 7000: starting
2013-02-18 02:36:49,624 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 6 on 7000: starting
2013-02-18 02:36:49,624 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 5 on 7000: starting
2013-02-18 02:36:49,624 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 4 on 7000: starting
2013-02-18 02:36:49,624 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 3 on 7000: starting
2013-02-18 02:36:49,624 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 7000: starting
2013-02-18 02:36:49,624 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 7000: starting
2013-02-18 02:36:49,625 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 7000: starting
2013-02-18 02:36:49,632 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 7000: starting
2013-02-18 02:36:49,637 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2013-02-18 02:43:14,155 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of transactions: 0 Total time for transactions(ms): 0Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 0 SyncTimes(ms): 0 
2013-02-18 02:43:14,279 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hadoop cause:java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
2013-02-18 02:43:14,281 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 8 on 7000, call addBlock(/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info, DFSClient_-273997685, null) from 192.168.1.8:62962: error: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:696)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)
```

Что необходимо сделать для правильного выполнения?
P.S. Вообще в конфигурационном файле `hdfs-site.xml` содержимое следующее (никакого коэффициента 1 там нет)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>

<property>
 <name>dfs.replication</name>
 <value>2</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Comment: 2013-02-18 02:43:14,279 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hadoop cause:java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1

Похоже на проблемы с правами доступа к файловой системе. Из под какого пользователея запущен hadoop и его процессы? Есть ли у этого пользователя доступ к на чтение/запись соответствующих директорий файловой системы?

Comment: @a_gura `hadoop` запущен из под пользователя `hadoop`. А указанного в ошибке пути вообще не существует на том узле, на котором я запускал скрипт, при этом владелец папки `/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/` (в которой есть только папка `dfs`) пользователь `hadoop` и права на нее `rwxrwxrwx` (0777).

Comment: @ivan31 "А указанного в ошибке пути вообще не существует на том узле"

Может он как раз и пытается создать эти директории и файл.

Comment: @a_gura есть такая программа `WinSCP`, которая отражает файловую систему указанного хоста, в моем случае, виртуальной машины на которой установлен `Linux`. В ней в свойствах указанных папок отображаются права `rwxrwxrwx` (0777).